# Pivot table in datagridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I could use some hints on a problem i am stuck with,

I have a datatable with 3 columns(Username, time, event) that I extract from an excel file
I need to count the number of events and how much time they spend on it per user and present this in datagridviewer control. any idea apprecited
Here is part of my code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
    TextBox1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Text
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = String.Format(ConnectionNoHeader, FileName)}
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(
            <Text>
                SELECT 
                Log_date,
                   username,
                        event,
                           time,
                             DateDiff('n', Min(time),Max(time)) as Duration
                FROM [<%= SheetName %>$]


WHERE Log_Date = <%= TextBox1.Text %> GROUP BY username
            </Text>.Value,
                cn
        )
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        dt.AcceptChanges()
        bsData.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsData
    End Using
```

end sub

Comment: The easiest would probably be using a 3rd party control. [First result from google](http://www.viblend.com/Questions/WinForms/HowToCreateAPivotTable.aspx).

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Well with this code I got nothing on datagrid

Comment: Are you getting any rows in your DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I have found a very simple solution which I hope might help someone out there.  It is a very easy way to create a pivot table and display it in a DGV. The DGV automatically creates all the necessary columns. Sorry, I don't have any reputation to post an image of the resulting DGV

```
  MyDGV.DataSource = GetPivotTable(MySQLcommand)

  Private Function GetPivotTable2(ByVal a_SQLCommand As String) As DataTable

  'Pivot table SQL structure
  'TRANSFORM SUM(ValueField) AS SumOfValueFIeld
  'SELECT RowHeadingField, RowHeadingField, ..., TotalField 
  'FROM TableName
  'WHERE SelectionClause
  'GROUP BY FirstRowField, SecondRowField...
  'PIVOT ColumnHeadingField

  'Example SQL:
  'TRANSFORM SUM(Hours]) AS [SUMHours]
  'SELECT [Member]
  'FROM TimesheetTable
  'WHERE ([Date] >= #7/01/2019# AND [Date] < #7/01/2020#)
  'GROUP BY [Member]
  'PIVOT [Activity]
  ‘This example creates a row for each Member and totals their hours under 
  ‘each activity

  Try

    Dim PivotTable As New DataTable
    Using Connection = New OleDbConnection(MyConnectionString)
      If Connection IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim Expression As New OleDbCommand(a_SQLCommand, Connection)
        Connection.Open()
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(Expression)
        da.Fill(PivotTable)
      End If
    End Using
    Return PivotTable

  Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Return Nothing
  End Try
End Function
```